# SIM800L Auto Connect..!

Tags: microcontroller, rf, gsm

I want to know does the SIM800L module connect to the network automatically without any user commands?

Because some modules will disconnect in low signal areas & some SIMs will be disconnected by service providers until we pay the monthly bills.

I do not set or poll any network related commands on power up, I just set some SMS commands & Echo off only.The modules works nicely on workbench but not sure above will happen in one day...!!

Comment: What does its documentation say? Did you read it?

Comment: Datasheet doesn't say anything thats why I asked here.No where mentioned it will autoconnect or not.